# Pass an object to a function in python without pre-defining it

Tags: python, function

I would like to pass a data frame to a function without defining it first or wrapping within the function. I am currently doing

```
def transform_df(df, column, threshold):
    return df[df[column]<threshold]


df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[1, 1.5, 2, 3],
                   'columnB':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})

df = df.rename(columns={'columnB':'columnC'})

df = transform_df(df, 'columnA', 2)
```

I would like to pass `df` into `transform_df()` without defining it first. So something like

```
df \
.rename(columns={'columnB':'columnC'}) \
.transform(df, 'columnA', 2)
```

In `R` I am aware you can use piping and pass `.` explicitly in place of `df`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "extend" the `DataFrame` class with a new member method (commonly called "monkey patching") by doing this:

```py
pd.DataFrame.transform_df = transform_df
```

and then call it with the `.` without passing the `df` param (it's automatically passed as the first arg to the function:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={'columnB':'columnC'}).transform_df('columnA', 2)
```

Comment: note: the convention for the name of the 1st param in such a function is `self`, but you can leave it as `df` if you want